# Portability of sending values stored in char array using MPI

Tags: c, mpi

If I have a char array that represents, for example, integer value(s), and I used it to send these values via MPI with the appropriate MPI datatype for send and receive operations as follows:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

    int  my_rank; /* rank of process */
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &my_rank); 

    unsigned char buff[100];

    if (my_rank == 0){
        int n = 99;

        int i;
        for(i = 0; i < sizeof(n);  i++){
            buff[i] = (n >> (8 * i)) & 0xFF;
        }

        MPI_Send(&buff, 1, MPI_INT, 1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }
    else{
        MPI_Recv(&buff, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, NULL);

        int n = *(int *)buff;
        printf("%d\n", n);
    }

    /* shut down MPI */
    MPI_Finalize(); 

    return 0;
}
```

Is this portable across machines of different architecture/endiness?

I suspect the only part that is not portable is the conversion from integer value to char array:

```
int i;
for(i = 0; i < sizeof(n);  i++){
    buff[i] = (n >> (8 * i)) & 0xFF;
}
```

But, anyways if not, is there a way to make the above program fully portable with the existence of the char array to store value(s)?

Comment: The `int n = *(int *)buff;` line is also non portable. Depending on the machine's endianness and `int` size it will print different values.

Comment: @atturri Is it? Using MPI_INT will not take care of arranging the bytes correctly in the buffer of receiving process?

Answer (score 0):

The way you serialize integers into a buffer is not portable. But if you are sending the integer, why not send integers directly, just take endianness into account. Suppose you want to sent 32bits integers:

```
int n = 99;
int sent = htonl(n);
MPI_Send(&send, 1, MPI_INT, 1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

For receiving:

```
int n;
int recv;
MPI_Recv(&recv, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, NULL);
n = ntonl(recv);
```